# "Display driver stopped working and has recovered" when running CUDA code

Tags: cuda

I have been running some CUDA code on my GTX 960m GPU. Once I got an error saying that the display driver stopped working and has recovered. Will that create any problem or issues to my graphic card?

Comment: It's more than likely just your OS responding to an unresponsive graphics driver. Are you doing a lot of work in a single kernel? If the GPU is busy for a long period of time (about 5 seconds if I recall correctly) the OS will interrupt it and try to recover from what it thinks is a problem. P.s. if this also happens when not running CUDA, look into update your Intel HD graphics chip drivers. I have had a similar issue occur there when browsing Youtube in Chrome for example.

Comment: That's a common problem, and AFAIK can have 2 reasons: 1. It might be that there's a bug in your kernel (accessing invalid memory regions or so). 2. It might be that the kernel simply takes more than 2 seconds to compute. Have a look at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/459869/-quot-display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-quot-wddm-timeout-detection-and-recovery-/ . It should in no case cause any problems to your graphics card. (If the card is too busy and not cooled properly, it may overheat etc, but this is *unrelated* to this error message).

Comment: The watchdog reset mechanism is intended to stop situations where a PC becomes unresponsive because a user process won't yield the GPU and the display (and eventually everything else) freezes for long periods. It is not harmful otherwise. The answer really a duplicate of a number of older questions, so I have closed it as a duplicate of one of those.